# Как отловить ошибку загрузки фрейма?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Если фрейм не загрузился по причине недоступности сервера (ошибка 503 или 404), как это дело отловить?

Пробовал ставить обработчик на `iframeElement.onerror`, но без толку.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

1) Отдельный ajax запрос, по адресу который подгружает iframe.

```js
function change() {
  var url = $('#addr').val();
  $.ajax(url, {
    success: function() {
      alert('Ok');
      $('#browse').attr('src', url);
    },
    error: function() {
      alert('Fail');
    }
  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="addr" />
<input type="button" value="Go" onclick="change();" />
<iframe id="browse" style="width:100%;height:100%"></iframe>
```

2) С помощью таймера.

```js
var iframeError;

function change() {
  var url = $("#addr").val();
  $("#browse").attr("src", url);
  iframeError = setTimeout("error()", 5000);
}

function load(e) {
  alert(e);
}

function error() {
  alert('error');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#browse').on('load', (function() {
    load('ok');
    clearTimeout(iframeError);
  }));

});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="addr" />
<input type="button" value="Go" onclick="change();" />
<iframe id="browse" style="width:100%;height:100%"></iframe>
```